# Click handler event listene

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been searching all over the place and even if I have found the answer, it has not been delivered in terms I can understand. I'm playing around with this code on jsfiddle, trying to understand why this click handler is not working. I apologize if this is a useless post, just trying to make sense of it all. If anyone knows any good tutorials on how JavaScript code is rendered and how functions pass objects etc.. please, do link me! I've read the basics of how to write functions etc.. but understanding whats going on when the code is parsed, to me, is quite a different thing.

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/UumUP/3144/

```
// Function to change the content of t2  
function modifyText(evt) {  
  var thing = evt.target;
  thing.firstChild.nodeValue = "four";      
}  

// add event listener to t  
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("td");  
    
for(i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener("click", modifyText(evt), false);   
}
```

Comment: OT: `:-O`  Are you really having 3144 revisions of the same code? You don't have to click `Update` to run and test your code, click `Run`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function and passing the result of that call, rather than passing a reference of the function, do this instead:

```
el[i].addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UumUP/3145/

Comment: So when the event listener is triggered, modifyText is called and because i have evt in the arguments it passes the event object into the function being called, so I can reference it?

Comment: @MarcCasavant you are passing the function reference somewhere and the browser will call that function with proper arguments when the event happens. It doesn't matter if you have `evt` in as a parameter, the argument is passed either way. You can always reference passed arguments with `arguments[0]` for first argument, `arguments[1]` for second argument and so on

Comment: So why is it that the code won't work if I remove the evt argument from the arguments in the modifyText function?

Comment: @MarcCasavant Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UumUP/3147/ did you refer to the passed argument at all?

Comment: That works fine, I'm still confused and trying to understand how putting evt in the arguments part of the function works. Whats going on that is causing the evt in the arguments to take the event object? Sorry if that does not make sense, I'm new at this.

Comment: Yes that does make sense, and I get that you can access it through an arguments array. The function also seems to work if I use evt as an argument, and I'm wondering why it works that way. Why am I not forced to use the arguments array? Is it just that the arguments array is being passed into the evt argument?

Comment: Defining parameters is more convenient, the arguments array is mainly used when you can expect any amount of arguments to your function like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2FfCA/

Comment: So basically, if an object is being passed to a function the arguments are going there either way, one way to access them is through the arguments array, and another is by putting your own argument in so you don't have to type out arguments[0] etc..

Comment: @MarcCasavant yes exactly, and you can name the first argument in event listener anything you want and refer that, it doesn't have to be called `evt`

Comment: Do you know of a resource that explains in greater detail how data is passed around between functions etc.. and how other parts of JS work? The w3schools site seems to be lacking. I've been trying to learn JS and programming in general for a while and I always end up getting confused as to what the code is doing when its executed. Also thanks for all your help so far, I was so lost..

Comment: @MarcCasavant https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions should cover it, also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: @Marc: For information regarding event handling, have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html and http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript as well. Maybe http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript is useful  too.

Answer (score 0):

```
el[i].addEventListener("click", modifyText(evt), false);
```

supposed to be

```
el[i].addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UumUP/3146/)**